# RetroPie | Display main screen on vnc viewer

Tags: screen, vnc, retropie

I am attempting to set up my raspberry pi as a portable gaming solution using a USB battery power bank, PI and IPad (For the Screen).

I have tried installing TightVNCServer in combination with x11vnc to allow me to display the main screen but I am unable to, all I can see is the RetroPie Console.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

RPi VC4 engine will not work on video card other than HDMI port, so you will not get any 2D/3D and/or hardware video enc/dec effects on your remote desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Type emulationstation. See if that starts Emulation Station.